# How to download SQL Server 2012 Express using webpicmd.exe commandline tool

Tags: sql-server-2012, web-platform-installer

I need to download SQL Server 2012 Express using webpicmd tool. But I could download SQL Server Express using webpicmd but it defaults to SQL Server 2008 Express. I would like to know how to download SQL Server 2012 Express using webpicmd. Any help would be appreciated